How to properly link libsndfile when compiling a standalone file using gcc
I'm using the libsndfile library for a signal processing project. I'm compiling c code using gcc on a WSL Ubuntu shell. I installed libsndfile-dev using sudo apt-get install libsndfile1-dev, as well as built the cloned libsndfile repository following its instructions on GitHub. As a test, I'm attempting to run https://github.com/libsndfile/libsndfile/blob/master/examples/make_sine.c outside the repository (it successfully generated the WAV file when ran within) by including the apt-get installed version.
When gcc make_sine.c is run, it generates the following errors:
make_sine.c:(.text+0x8d): undefined reference to `sf_open'
/usr/bin/ld: make_sine.c:(.text+0xed): undefined reference to `sin'
/usr/bin/ld: make_sine.c:(.text+0x15f): undefined reference to `sin'
/usr/bin/ld: make_sine.c:(.text+0x1a9): undefined reference to `sin'
/usr/bin/ld: make_sine.c:(.text+0x200): undefined reference to `sf_close'
/usr/bin/ld: make_sine.c:(.text+0x232): undefined reference to `sf_write_int'
/usr/bin/ld: make_sine.c:(.text+0x24f): undefined reference to `sf_strerror'
/usr/bin/ld: make_sine.c:(.text+0x263): undefined reference to `sf_close'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I believe this is because the library is not properly linked in the gcc command. However, when I attempt to link the library, calling instead gcc make_sine.c -l sndfile, it generates the following errors:
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccpubl3O.o: undefined reference to symbol 'sin@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
/usr/bin/ld: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Q8 of http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/FAQ.html specifies how to use libsndfile once it's installed. I've run all three commands, however, the final command simply generated the same output as gcc make_sine.c.
tl;dr: How do I properly compile make_sine.c outside of the libsndfile repository so that it generates a WAV file?

The problem is that you have to link the glibc math libraries in addition to libsdnfile. Running gcc make_sine.c -lm -lsndfile produces the correct output (sine.wav) upon execution of a.out. This works regardless of whether you use the apt-get version or run make install in a compiled cloned version of the libsndfile github.

Seems like your gcc couldn't find a libsndfile. You could compile with pkgconfig usage or with just a linker only. In both ways you need to be sure that your program could find library. First of all, find a full path to libsndfile using
sudo find / -name "*sndfile*".
Then this path you just need to add in search path. For pkgconfig use export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/"your path to pkgconfig folder witch contains sndfile.pc".
For linker just add -Lpath to .so file to yours compiler comand. For example:
gcc make_sine.c -L/usr/lib -lsndfile -o your_program.

After running export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/"/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/sndfile.pc", running gcc make_sine.c -L/usr/lib -lsndfile -o your_program produces the same output as gcc make_sine.c -l sndfile. Is it possible the apt-get version of libsndfile was compiled against a different version of glibc than is on my machine? If so, how would I rectify that?

first of all. PKG_CONFIG_PATH shouldn't contain path with pkg name(only containing dirrectory). About glibc: if you get it with apt-get it should be ok. If you compilled it by yourself it's possible that diffs between linked glibc and yours too much. And try add path to libm.so* using -L/"path" -lm construction. Maybe it shoud help.  I'm personally compilled glibc and libsndfile with my own gcc compiler from source code, and it workes just fine.

My specific problem ended up being that I wasn't linking the glibc math libraries when compiling make_sine.c (which imports math.h), not a problem with libsndfile itself. Regardless, thank you for all your help.
